# Can I use my Xbox 360 Battlefield 3 Premium account on the PC version?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

I purchased Battlefield 3 Premium Edition for the Xbox 360 and have a high level with a ton of stuff unlocked already. I was wondering if it's possible to continue to play with that Premium account on the PC. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no way to transfer the character between platforms.

Comment: Ok thank you. I wish i could though lol. Sucks that i have to repurchase premium and continue to re-level up, but oh well.